# Smart Pretty Printing DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, pretty-print

It may be that I need to implement this myself, but I figured I'd at least ask if there is some kind of a library or something in existence before I do so.

I'm looking to take a DateTime and pretty print it into things like

> "Thursday at 1pm"
>
> "Tomorrow at 8am"

or

> "10 minutes from now"

Essentially taking a DateTime that is in the future and displaying it in a human readable string relative to the current date.

Like I said, if this something I gotta do myself - "Challenge Accepted" but I felt it was worth a quick question!

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/pretty-date-generator

Comment: We write the strings to styled HTML pages and print it from a browser, might be helpful and we find it easier for non-developers to change then. Might be helpful, you can either use if statements to change the day difference to sting but I am sure .NET has this built in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Humanizer](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer) I think it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses! Humanizer is the way I should go, does exactly what I want! Will accept this answer as soon as it'll let me (it says 8 minutes right now)

Comment: Humanizer is 16000 lines / 200 files of c#.
If all you want is the date functionality you could probably write a < 50 line function to do the job...